# Pivoting a dynamic column based on split value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I Have a couple of tables as per below

**Position table**

| Id | PositionName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Developer |
| 2 | Analyst |
| 3 | Tester |

**Employee table**

| Id | Name | Positions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | `1,2` |
| 2 | Lisa | `3` |
| 3 | Smith | `1` |
| 4 | Willow | `NULL` |
| 5 | Burly | `2,3` |

From the above tables, what is the query to produce a pivoted report as per below?

| Id | Name | Developer | Analyst | Tester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Y | Y | N |
| 2 | Lisa | N | N | Y |
| 3 | Smith | Y | N | N |
| 4 | Willow | N | N | N |
| 5 | Burly | N | Y | Y |

I am stuck with the fact I have to do some split string and use the `CASE` `WHEN` to apply `Y` or `N` to the pivot.

here's my playground in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ad8d/31

Comment: I strongly recommend you unpivot that `Positions` column into a separate table, and that you upgrade to a more modern and supported version of SQL Server

Comment: ikr. thats what supposed to be done. but I have an old piece of technology that need to be maintained with short amount of time. normalize the table wasn't option due to existing data and application that works on the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble getting Fiddle to work right now, but the code isn't too bad to just reproduce in full. Note that you should watch your @Cols variable to make sure all of your  position names work as column names in real life, that's often not the case! Also note that your original example had duplicate employee IDs, I gave them unique values.

```
CREATE  table Position (
  Id int,
  Name varchar(10)
);

insert into Position values
(1, 'Developer'),
(2, 'Analyist'),
(3, 'Tester');

CREATE table Employee (
  Id int,
  Name varchar(10),
  Position varchar(MAX)
);

insert into Employee values
(1, 'John', '1,3'),
(2, 'Lisa', '3'),
(3, 'Smith', '1'),
(4, 'Willow', NULL),
(5, 'Burly', '2,3');

--This is your basic working PIVOT, we'll implement as a dynamic query once we're satisfied it works
;with cteEmp as (
    SELECT E.Id as EID, E.Name as EName, P.Name as PName
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), P.Id)
            , CONCAT(',', E.Position, ',') ) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as HasPos 
    FROM Employee as E CROSS JOIN Position as P
)SELECT Piv.* FROM cteEmp as E PIVOT (max(HasPos) FOR PName in (Developer, Analyist, Tester)) as Piv;


--To make it dynamic, build the list of positions from a query
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
    FROM Position
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'with cteEmp as (
    SELECT E.Id as EID, E.Name as EName, P.Name as PName
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), P.Id)
            --, CONCAT('','', E.Position, '','') ) > 0 --Not 2008R2!
            , '','' + E.Position + '','' ) > 0  
               THEN ''Y'' ELSE ''N'' END as HasPos 
    FROM Employee as E CROSS JOIN Position as P
)SELECT Piv.* FROM cteEmp as E PIVOT (max(HasPos) 
FOR PName in (' + @cols + ') ) as Piv;'

execute(@query)
```

EDIT: Fixed the missing close parenthesis in the dynamic query.

EDIT: Note: This does not use a split function, it takes advantage of the facts that the ID must be an integer and the positions listed are delimited in a predictable way. We don't need a list of position IDs, we only need to know if the position ID in question is in the list. We prepend and append commas so we can search on ",1," and not just "1" because "1" would also match "21" but ",1," only matches the single ID.

Comment: thanks @Robert, it work as expected, yet this one doesn't need additional function to do split string. 
one thing, the dynamic part missing closing bracket `)` just before `as Piv`

Comment: Thanks @yokaii, good catch on the missing parenthesis (I can't get sqlFiddler working for me today for some reason so testing was a problem) and I added an explanation for why my solution doesn't use the SPLIT function. You could certainly make it work using the split function, but this has fewer external dependencies. If you try it both ways you might report back on performance differences, I'd be curious.

Comment: and the other problem is `CONCAT` didn't work in SQL 2008 R2, but I get the idea on how the query is compiled. I just need to find substitution to deal with `CONCAT` and I have to avoid the additional custom function to do split string. the reason is because the query will be managed somewhere in the application to produce one time report and can be changed at anytime.

Comment: Doh! Sorry @yokaii , I changed my original "CONTAINS" to "CHARINDEX" to account for 2008R2 but I forgot CONCAT was newer too! You should be able to replace the CONCAT with `'','' + E.Position + '',''` in 2008R2. This doesn't use the SPLIT function so you should be good there. Also, don't forget to Accept (it works) and/or upvote (it's informative or innovative) the answer to help future searchers identify solutions worth looking at in detail.

Comment: yes, I do the plus `+` concatenation workaround and it works perfectly. I do not have enough time to run the query profiling for the performance. thinking this will be used to generate one time only reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join `Position` table to get the name of the position

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
    FROM Position
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @query = N'
SELECT Name,' + @cols + N'
from 
(
    SELECT e.Name, p.PositionName
    FROM Employee AS e
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(Position, '','') AS ep(PositionId)
    JOIN Position AS p ON p.Id = ep.PositionId
) x
pivot 
(
    COUNT(*)
    FOR p.PositionName IN (' + @cols + N')
) p
';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```